# Legendre symbol: Showing that $\sum_{m=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{am+b}{p}\right)=0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, legendre-symbol

I have a question about Legendre symbol. 
Let $a$, $b$ be integers. Let $p$ be a prime not dividing $a$. Show that the Legendre symbol verifies:
$$\sum_{m=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{am+b}{p}\right)=0.$$

I know that $\displaystyle\sum_{m=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{m}{p}\right)=0$, but how do I connect this with the previous formula? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show that as $m$ ranges from $0$ to $p-1$, $am$ ranges over all residue classes modulo $p$, and hence $am+b$ ranges over all residue classes modulo $p$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530467/sum-of-legendre-symbols-sum-n-1p-left-fracanbp-right-0 and
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666704/a-problem-with-the-legendre-jacobi-symbols-sum-n-1p-left-fracanbp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow the question to be marked as answered, then:

Show that as $m$ ranges from $0$ to $p−1$, $am$ ranges over all residue classes modulo $p$, and hence $am+b$ ranges over all residue classes modulo $p$.