# Summation Series of Legendre Symbols

Tags: number-theory, summation

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and put $$s(a, p) = 
\sum_{n=1}^{p} (\frac{n(n+a)}{p}) $$

Show that:

(i)  $\sum_{a=1}^{p}s(a, p) = 0.$

(ii) If $(a, p) = 1$ then $ s(a, p) = s(1, p).$

(iii) Conclude that $s(a, p) = −1$ if $(a, p) = 1.$

I've tried (i) and I think that the proof relies on $\sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac{n}{p}=0 $, however I don't know how to show this result. (ii) and (iii) I am unsure of as well.

Comment: (i) Cannot be true: $n>0\Rightarrow s > 0 \Rightarrow \sum s > 0$

Comment: Again (we discussed this, remember?), the sum is miswritten: Legendre symbol $(a/p)$ is not the fraction $a/p$. The Legendre symbol can be $0$, $1$ or $-1$. For your last question, see [this duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666704/a-problem-with-the-legendre-jacobi-symbols-sum-n-1p-left-fracanbp?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks for saying, I've edited it now